# Get posts from multiple users in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In my site, I have a table of `Users`. `Users` can follow each other. A user can created any number of `Post`'s.

I want to be able to see the most recent `Post`'s from the users I've followed.

Currently my models are defined like this:

**User Model:**

```
 class User extends Authenticatable
    {
    public function followers(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Follower', 'following');
    }
    public function following(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Follower', 'id');
    }
    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'createdby');
    }
 }
```

**Follower Model:**

```
class Follower extends Model
{
    public function postsFollowing(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'createdby', 'following');
    }
}
```

**Post Model:**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'createdby', 'id');
    }
}
```

My tables are as such:

```
Table Name,      column names
User              id,  name
Follower          id,  following
Post              id,  created_by
```

In the `Follower` table, `id` represents the user, and `following` represents the user being followed. If user 3 follows user 537, then `id = 3`, `following = 537`. Hope that made sense.

**What I've tried:**

1. `User::following()->posts` - doesn't work because
   `User::following()` returns an Eloquent Collection object. You have
   to loop through this
2. Looping through my followed users to get their `Post`'s - This
   doesn't work either since I want to get the top n entries sorted by
   date.

**Update #1**

Follower Model (Updated)

```
class Follower extends Model
{
    public function followingPosts(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Post', 'App\Follower',
            'following', 'createdby', 'id'
        );
    }
}
```

Controller

```
$user = Auth::user();
$posts = $user->followingPosts;
```

I updated followingPosts() in the Follower class with the above. The result: `$posts` is `null`

**Update #2**

I moved the followingPosts() to the User model:

```
public function followingPosts(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Post', 'App\Follower',
        'following', 'createdby'
    );
}
```

Controller:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$posts = $user->followingPosts;
```

Now I just get all posts, even from the users I didn't follow.

Comment: Have you tried using the hasManyThrough method?

Comment: I have not. Checking it out now

Comment: Can you share your tables (structure)? Not able to get a clear idea without the table structure.

Comment: Just added the table structure

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement - "Users can follow each other. A user can created any number of Post's. Being able to list recent posts (limited to number) of followers or whom user is following".

You can define many-to-many relationship on the User Model (Many-To-Many relationship on self - User Model).

Create two Pivot tables

**Follower-User Pivot Table**

```
class CreateFollowerUserPivotTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('follower_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('follower_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('follower_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->primary(['follower_id', 'user_id']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('follower_user');
    }
}
```

**Following-User Pivot Table**

```
class CreateFollowingUserPivotTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('following_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('following_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('following_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->primary(['following_id', 'user_id']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('following_user');
    }
}
```

Then define the relationships in your User Model

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function followers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'follower_user', 'user_id', 'follower_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function following()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'following_user', 'following_id', 'user_id' )->withTimestamps();
    }

    //Assuming posts table has user_id as foreign key

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }

    //Assuming posts table has user_id as foreign key
    public function recent_posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->take(10)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }
}
```

Now to get who a given user is following

```
//Say for example we take the logged in user

$user = User::with('following.recent_posts')->whereEmail(auth()->user()->email);

foreach($user->following as $following)
{
    $posts = $following->recent_posts;
}
```

Hope this is what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go, no point in defining a new Model for the followers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`has-many-through`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) for this as:

```
public function followingPosts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Post', 'App\Follower',
        'follow', 'createdby', 'id'
    );
}
```

Then you can access the posts as:

```
$user->followingPosts; // returns collection of post model
```

*Note: Assuming you have a `follow` column in `Follower` table.*

Comment: I modified the code to match yours, but now I'm not getting any results. 
    `$user = Auth::user();
    $posts = $user->followingPosts;
    if($posts == null){$posts = array();}
    return view('home')->with('posts', $posts);`

Comment: In your `Follower` table how you are mapping which user followed other users? I mean you are not saving `following_id` and `follow_id`.

Comment: In the Follower table, `id` is the follower, `following` is the id of the person being followed.

Comment: Could you clarify whether the `followingPosts()` should be in `User` or `Follower`? If it is in `Follower`, then why am I able to access it with `$user->followingPosts()`?

Comment: It should be in `User` model.